# pytest - default fixture parameter value

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I wrote a fixture in pytest which was not parametrized but is used by a lot of tests. Later I needed to parametrize this fixture.

In order to not to have to `mark.parametrize` all the old tests I did the following:

```
def ldap_con(request):
    try:
        server_name = request.param
    except AttributeError:
        server_name = "ldaps://my_default_server"
    c = Connection(server_name, use_ssl=True)
    yield c
    c.unbind()
```

Now I can have both:

```
def test_old(ldap_con):
    run_test_to_default_connection(ldap_con)


@pytest.mark.parametrize('ldap_con', ['mynewserver'], indirect=True)
def test_new(ldap_con):
    run_test_to_new_connection(ldap_con)
```

The solution has several drawbacks:

- I am catching an arbitrary Attribute Error (there might be another)
- It does not take into account named parameters
- It is not clear to a reader that there is a default value

**Is there a standard way to define a default value for a fixture parameter?**

Comment: Your approach with supplying the fixture with a default value looks good to me; I do it the same way. The only thing I would improve is using [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) as it can provide a default value: `server_name = getattr(request, 'param', 'ldaps://my_default_server')`

Answer (score 1):

How about

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def server_name() -> str:
    """default value for server_name"""
    return "ldaps://my_default_server"


@pytest.fixture
def ldap_con(server_name: str):
    c = Connection(server_name, use_ssl=True)
    yield c
    c.unbind()
```

We can have both

```py
def test_old(ldap_con):
    run_test_to_default_connection(ldap_con)


@pytest.mark.parametrize('server_name', ['mynewserver'])
def test_new(ldap_con):
    run_test_to_new_connection(ldap_con)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Indirect parametrization is messy. To avoid that, I usually write fixture so that it returns a function. I will end up writing it this way:

```
def ldap_con():
    def _ldap_con(server_name="ldaps://my_default_server"):
        c = Connection(server_name, use_ssl=True)
        yield c
        c.unbind()
    return _ldap_con

def test_old(ldap_con):
    run_test_to_default_connection(ldap_con())


@pytest.mark.parametrize('server', ['mynewserver'])
def test_new(server):
    run_test_to_new_connection(ldap_con(server))
```